# How to handle circular references with Autofac 2.4.5?

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, circular-dependency, property-injection

The autofac wiki page about [Circular References](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/CircularDependencies) says to use:

```
cb.Register<DependsByProp>().OnActivated(ActivatedHandler.InjectUnsetProperties);
```

But it looks like **ActivatedHandler** does not exist anymore in 2.4.5. Digging around in the source, I found the implementation of that class, and so I put in the method implementation in the OnActivated instead. Unfortunately, it this still doesn't work.

I've put together a minimal repro here that looks like what was on the Wiki page.

```
class M
{
    public VM VM { get; set; }

    public M()
    {
    }
}

class VM
{
    public VM(M m)
    {
    }
}

[Fact]
void CanResolveCircular()
{
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<VM>();
    builder.RegisterType<M>().OnActivated(e => e.Context.InjectUnsetProperties(e.Instance));

    using (var container = builder.Build())
    {
        var m = container.Resolve<M>();
        Assert.NotNull(m);
    }
}
```

This code still throws a stack overflow exception as a Resolve is attempted. What am I missing? What is the correct way to get Autofac to handle circular dependencies?

Comment: Yes. I thought that circular dependencies meant the same as instance cycles. Your answer below pointed out what I was missing about concepts of circular dependencies between classes and instances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Autofac documentation for [circular dependencies](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/circular-dependencies.html) states:

> Note, it doesn't make sense to set up
>   this scenario if both classes are
>   registered with Factory scope.

Both your `M` and `VM` registrations are `InstancePerDependency` (previously known as `FactoryScope`) so this statement applies to your scenario.  As a result, you get in an endless loop of creating M and VM instances.

If you want the property injected `VM` to take the *same instance* of `M` that you resolve, you should change the lifetime of `M` to something other than `InstancePerDependency` (e.g. `SingleInstance`).  This is shown below:

```csh
builder.RegisterType<M>().PropertiesAutowired(true).SingleInstance();
```

*Note: I'm also using the more recent PropertiesAutowired(true) extension method.   You can use this in place of the OnActivated code in your repro.*

If you don't want a single instance of `M` per app, you could setup a [`LifetimeScope`](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/NewInV2#Lifetime_and_Scope) and use `InstancePerLifetimeScope`.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone interested here is the new way of doing this:

```
class DependsByProp1
{
    public DependsByProp2 Dependency { get; set; }
}

class DependsByProp2
{
    public DependsByProp1 Dependency { get; set; }
}

// ...

var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
cb.RegisterType<DependsByProp1>()
      .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
      .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
cb.RegisterType<DependsByProp2>()
      .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
      .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
```

[Property/Property Dependencies](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/CircularDependencies)